# Error while installing dotnet-ef in azure pipeline

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm generating ef migration scripts in azure pipelines,
for that I'm performing the following tasks:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Install EF Tool
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install --global dotnet-ef'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Create SQL Scripts
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: 'ef '
      nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{ parameters.nugetConfigPath }}'        
      arguments: 'migrations script  --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/sql/sqlscript.sql --idempotent --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{ parameters.startupProjectPath }}  --context AdministrationMigrationDBContext
```

For the first time when I run the pipeline, the sql script generated successfully. But the next time I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I'm getting an error while installing dotnet-ef saying "Tool dotnet-ef  already installed". Can someone help me in resolving this?

Comment: Self-hosted runner? Tool caching? Operating system? Containerized runner or does runner retain its changes between runs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dotnet tool update`, which acording to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-update#description) basically re-installs the tool:

> The dotnet tool update command provides a way for you to update .NET tools on your machine to the latest stable version of the package. The command **uninstalls and reinstalls** a tool, effectively updating it.

Comment: does it install it if it's not there?